# How can I build AutoEncoder for a-one-class unsupervised classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders, anomaly-detection

I am studying AutoEncoder to learn how to build a-one-class classification model which is unsupervised learning and I am wondering how to build a-one-class classification model using AutoEncoder. After having done my researches and I got some questions in mind:

- Does AutoEncoder need backpropagations?
- Does AutoEncoder require the same weights as in the encoder and decoder parts?
- If I want to detect outlier ones, do I only train the model with non-outlier ones?
- After having trained an AutoEncoder, how can I test it as a-one-class classification model?

Answer (score 1):

AutoEncoder is not a classifier, but you can use it as a layer before your classification layers.
The reason to use AutoEncoder is to get a better representation of your input, you can think of it as a dimensionality reduction technique like PCA (but a nonlinear one).
In order to build an end to end classifier with AutoEncoder you can do the following:

Build the following neural network:
Given the input is X, pass it via several layers and output a dense vector D. D will be your dense input representation.
Given D you now have two tasks:

- Classification task: Take D as an input and pass it via several layers with sigmoid as final activation to get the classification output Y*. The loss for this task will be a simple cross entropy loss with the label and the output Y*.
- AutoEncoder auxiliary task: Take D as an input and try to reconstruct the input X. In order to do it, pass D via several layers and output a dense vector X*, with the same size as X. The loss for this task will be the average square distance between X and X*.

The final loss for your network will be a weighted average between the losses of these two tasks. Backpropagation is used for both tasks.
The model validation doesn't change. You still can calculate AUC for your test set using the label Y and the output Y*.

One way to implement it will be the following:

- Take X as an input, pass it via several fully connected layers and output a latent vector D
- Take D, pass it via additional fully connected layers and output a dense vector K, with the size of |X| + 1.
- The last element of the vector K will be your logits. pass it via sigmoid to get the probability Y*.
- The first |X| elements of vector K will be the reconstruction of X.
- Create a loss function L which is a weighted average of two losses. The first loss is a simple cross entropy loss between the label Y and the prediction Y*. The second loss is the euclidean distance between X and X*
- Finally minimize L via gradient descent optimizer

Comment: Do you mean the latent layer by the dense vector D in AutoEncoder?

Comment: yes. This latent layer is the encoding of your input.

Comment: As said, I can get the latent features from the latent layer after some iterations of AutoEncoder and use the latent vector as the input features for the classification model but how do I train the classifier for the dataset with only one class? Do I keep the encoding layer and replace the decoding layer with the classification layer with sigmoid function in the output layer and use cross-entropy for the cost function?

Comment: You keep the encoding layer, and then from this encoding layer you produce 2 outputs. One is your probability prediction (after the sigmoid) and the second is a dense layer X* which is the reconstruction of the input X. Then you combine the two losses, the simple cross-entropy loss and the second loss which is the difference between X and X*.

Comment: Not to complicate things (ofer-a is exactly right) but you don’t _have_ to produce 2 outputs (in what is called _multitask learning_, or _parallel transfer learning_). Instead, you could do one then the other. First train the autoencoder. Then remove the decoder and put the classifier on top of the encoder. Train the classifier. This is called _sequential transfer learning_.

Comment: @ofer-a 
Can you please update your answer with more details? I am kind of mixed up. I don't really understand how a one-class classification model is trained from your context.

Comment: @StoryMay added another section with implementation suggestion

Comment: The first loss is the simple cross entropy loss and indeed you have only one class and Y* is a single number that is compared to the label Y. The second loss is the auto-encoder loss. The purpose of it is to reconstruct the input X. i.e. get D as an input and output X*. Without this loss this will be a simple classification task that doesn't have AutoEncoder part.

Comment: @ofer-a
Thank you for the addition to the answer. I have a dataset with only one class and why do I use two different losses? I am confused with this part. I can only train the network with a one-class labeled dataset, so my network only understands the normals ones but abnormal ones will not be understand well so they become claimed as outliers when they are fed into the network. But how can I tell ones are outliers. I have just started learning AutoEncoder to use it for one-class classification.

Comment: The first one is classification loss. Without it, you’re not classifying. The second is autoencoding loss. Without it, you’re not autoencoding. When you say ‘one-class classification’, do you mean anomaly detection? Please update your question, e.g., to clarify whether you intend to do supervised or unsupervised anomaly detection.

Comment: I meant unsupervised learning and updated my question.

Comment: I need to delete my question. I think I mixed up my question with AutoEncoder and Tranfer Learning.